# User Impersonation from System Account service

Tags: c#, impersonation, windows-identity

I am Working on creation Windows Service using C#, running from System Account with background services.
I need to perform some task via service which need user login info, which I intend to share with user token, retrieved at run-time. and to impersonate the user I am making use of "WindowsIdentity" class. So my question is, Is it possible to impersonate the user in such way from System account? if it is, How ?